# Applying a 2D FFT to an image

Tags: typescript, fft

I've been trying to implement FFT with TypeScript and I want to apply it to an image data (which is a 128x128, grayscale 2D array). I'm thinking of the following steps but I'm not quite sure if I'm in the right direction.

Image Data:

```
[[1 2 3],
 [4 5 6],
 [7 8 9]]
```

1. Flatten 3x3 image data array to 1x9 (like [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9])
2. Apply FFT and calculate spectrum (for x axis)
3. Reshape spectrum array to 3x3
4. Transpose spectrum array
5. Flatten 3x3 spectrum array to 1x9 (like [1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9])
6. Apply FFT and calculate spectrum (for y axis)
7. Same as 3
8. Same as 4
9. Calculate power spectrum and plot

I actually got a very familiar result but somehow I'm not confident.

Script in action: https://tatsuky.com/playground/fft-ts/

Comment: No this is not right for a 2D FFT. Apply a 1D FFT to each of the rows separately. Then apply a 1D FFT to each of the columns of that result.

Comment: I fixed the code and now the result looks more decent.

Comment: The link is now dead.